# Undefined variable: data (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\complete.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-5

I have a controller called `simpleController` and here is the code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


class simpleController extends Controller {

public function complete() {
    $all_registration_info=DB::table('registration')->get();
    if (count($all_registration_info) > 0) {
        return view('complete',$all_registration_info);
    }else{
        return view('index');
    }
}
}
```

Then there is a class named as complete.blade.php and here is the code

```
<tbody>
    @foreach( $data as $value)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$value->id}}</th>
        <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->phone}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->password}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Do not know how to solve the undefined problem

Comment: where have you defined the   `$data` variable?

Comment: first I had tried like this
@foreach($all_contact_info as $view
But that also shown the same error. then i used $data variable as shown in a tutorial

Comment: Oh shit I found the error. There was a silly mistake. there should be like below...
$data['data'] = DB::table('registration')->get();
and then in the foreach loop
foreach($data as $value) will work. 
Thank you sir @WojtekT